# Battery icon changed?

Tags: 12.04, themes, indicator, battery, icons

I don't know what happened, but today when I logged in to Ubuntu 12.04, the battery icon looked strange (when unplugged):

[image]

When it's plugged, the icon looks as always been, the problem is when it's not plugged in:

[image]

I'm using ubuntu-mono-dark as the main theme, but trying to change the themes doesn't do anything, that "ugly" icon remains the same.

Any ideas if this is a bug or something? (or how to fix it)

Comment: It's a bug with time output...Sorry

Comment: Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: A bug report has been reported regarding this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1001229

Answer (score 3):

This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1001229) has since been resolved.

When the charger is plugged:

[image]

When unplugged:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Power -
Show battery status in the menu bar = **Never**

oh, and i installed AwOken icon theme
seems to have fixed the battery icon.