# Why battery icon on ubuntu-mono themes is broken?

Tags: 12.04, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery icon changed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138726/battery-icon-changed)

Battery icon on ubuntu-mono-dark theme didn't show up correctly:

[image]

Comment: Already check on jokerdino question, but the bugfix on the proposed repositry is not working.